# Trying to migrate SQL Server to MySQL using MySQL Workbench. Error: "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid argument value" when migrating data

Tags: mysql, database, migration, sql-server-2012, workbench

Long time lurker, first time poster; hoping anyone can help me out.

Im using MySQL Workbench 5.2.41 to migrate a database from SQL Server to MySQL 5.0.8

The entire process goes smoothly: both SQL and MySQL connection Tests are good, the skemea and table create as expected, everything checks out until the 'Bulk Data Transfer' step. At that point I receive this error:

```
...
Migrating data...
wbcopytables.exe --odbc-source=DSN=SQL Server 11;DATABASE=;UID=sa --target=root@127.0.0.1:3306 --progress --passwords-from-stdin --thread-count=1 --table [GSAClosers_v2] [dbo].[AccountBase] `dbo` `AccountBase`
`dbo`.`AccountBase`:Copying 84 columns of 169530 rows from table [GSAClosers_v2].[dbo].[AccountBase]

ERROR: `dbo`.`AccountBase`:SQLGetData: HY009:10:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid argument value `dbo`.`AccountBase`:

Finished copying 0 rows in 0m00s
Copy helper has finished
...
```

For connectors I'm using Microsoft SQL Server / ODBC Data Source / DSN: SQL Server and for MySQL the IP and port(3306).

SQL Server 2012 Management Studio connects and all operations work as expected.

O, side not: both are on the same localhost machine.

If anyone can shed some light on this I would be forever indebted. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it figured out: un-install java. install java 1.6, use MySQL Migration Tool. change all data types to varchar, ints and bits. run migrations....eat data.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/sqlgetstarted/thread/863bbea4-45fb-429c-94d9-838be24f9c7c):

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid argument value.
>   Regarding to the error message and code you provided, which seems is
>   database is invalid or cannot be accessed. That means either the
>   database does not exist or the user does not have permission to access
>   the database.
>
> It turns out you need specify the instance after the server name, so
>   in the server name in the dialog box for creating the ODBC Data
>   Source, you must enter it as either: MyServer\SQLEXPRESS or
>   .\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: More info:

Out of the 12 tables in this db one does convert as wanted. Others do not. Im thinking it is a size issue and 'SQLGetData' method. Anyone have similar issues?

@ Manik Baasha: Thank you for the idea, however, MySQL Workbench connects to both source an destinations without issue at the beginning of the process; is able to read the db objects, and converts the table structures, stored procedures and views without issue as well.

Comment: Found this:
HY009
Invalid use of null pointer
(DM) The argument TargetValuePtr was a null pointer.
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms715441(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: TargetValuePtr
[Output] Pointer to the buffer in which to return the data.
TargetValuePtr cannot be NULL.

Comment: Ok, got it figured out: un-install java. install java 1.6, use MySQL Migration Tool. change all data types to varchar, ints and bits. run migrations....eat data.

Comment: I'm fighting with this same issue. Are you saying that I need to downgrade my version of java?

Comment: That's what worked for me:
1 - Completely removed Java
2 - installed an archived 1.6 version
3 - then the old MySQL Migration tool.

At least in my case it was finally able to run the migration...all the 27Gig MsSQL db...

I also noticed that you basically have to change all the MySQL field types to very basic SQL types. Such as vchar(256), int, decimal, etc. One the migration is finished then convert to MySQL specific types as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have a problem connecting to your database from `wbcopytables.exe`. Keep in mind that this is a separate tool so the fact that you can connect from the rest of the Migration Wizard doesn't imply that you will connect in `wbcopytables.exe`.

The thing that worries me the most is that your DSN has whitespace characters. This might be interpreted by the Windows terminal as independent command line parameters. One thing you can do is to edit your DSN name removing the whitespaces and try again.

You may also want to connect without a DSN by putting all your connection parameters explicitely as explained in my blog post: [How-To: Guide to Database Migration from Microsoft SQL Server using MySQL Workbench](https://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/07/migrating-from-ms-sql-server-to-mysql-using-workbench-migration-wizard/).

And, by the way, since [MySQL Workbench 5.2.42](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html) is out you should go and get it. The Migration Wizard is pretty new so important bug fixes are likely launched in each recent Workbench release.

In either case I think you should [file a bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/report.php) with your issues with a detailed explanation about how to reproduce it, possible solutions, etc.

Hope this helps.